# OData - Adding fields to proxy partial class but need to ignore them in requests

Tags: c#, odata

I have an OData v4 service that I newly created. I have generated a proxy and connected to it successfully for all operations now.

I now want to add two properties in the generated proxy via a partial class sitting outside, example is given below:

```
public partial class ExchangeRate
{
    public DateTime? AddedOnDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOnDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I go to query the service I get an error on the "client" side (my side of the code, not service) that there is no settable properties in DateTime. I get that DateTime is not supported and it should be DateTimeOffset, my point is to find a way in which the proxy will ignore these properties while connecting to the service, something like an "ignore" attribute or something.

I tried putting the "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMappedAttribute" on each of the properties, it didn't work.

The error is originating from here : "Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.ValidateComplexTypeHasProperties"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it by making the properties internal, EF doesn't care wether the properties are public or not at least when I make a separate mapping class (EntityTypeConfiguration<>), OData proxy stopped picking those classes up.

The properties look like this now:

```
internal DateTime? AddedOnDateEF
    {
        get
        {
            if (!this.AddedOn.HasValue)
                return null;

            return this.AddedOn.Value.DateTime;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!value.HasValue)
                this.AddedOn = null;
            else
            {
                this.AddedOn = new DateTimeOffset(value.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the entity configuration class has this line in its constructor:

```
this.Property(t => t.AddedOnDateEF).HasColumnName("AddedOn");
this.Ignore(t => t.AddedOn);
```

The "AddedOn" property of type DateTimeOffset is in the OData proxy which is the other end of the partial class "ExchangeRate" shown in the example above.